# $[a,b)$ not closed

Tags: real-analysis

I understand this can easily be done by contradiction by I am slightly confused if I use a different method.

If $(x_n)$ is an arbitrary sequence, $x_n \in K$,  $\forall n>0$ and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x \in K \iff$ $K$ is closed

The negation of this is:

If $\exists$ a sequence $ (x_i)$  with $x_i \in K$ (where $K$ is a  set) $\forall i>0$ and $\lim \limits_{i \to \infty}x_i=x$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x \notin K \iff$ $K$ is not closed

However my lecturer has used $x_i=b-\frac{1}{i}$ which has the limit $b$ which is what we want as $b \notin [a,b)$, however $x_i$ does not necessarily $\in [a,b), \forall i>0$? For example $x_1=b-1$ may well be less than $a$ and hence $\notin [a,b)$?

Comment: Indeed, either we can take $x_i = b - (b-a)/i$ in which case $x_i$ is in $[a,b)$ for all $i>0$, or we can "truncate" the sequence; $\exists N$ s.t. $i>N \Rightarrow b-1/i\in[a,b)$, in which case the sequence $x_i = b-1/(i+N)$ has the desired property for $i>0$.

Comment: Woah woah woah people, I personally see absolutely no reason to downvote this question.  Remember: downvoting is meant for questions that haven't shown any effort, or maybe appear to be homework problems with no effort, or are totally unclear.  If you think this question is "dumb", just leave.  Don't start downvoting this student's effort to understand the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a great point.  But still, there is no problem here.  This is because with sequences, we are almost always concerned with the *end behavior* of the sequence.

If $x_{i}$ is not in $[a,b)$ for the first few $i$, that's okay.  We could just define a new sequence $y_{i}$ to be the sequence $x_{i}$ but only at the starting point where all successive terms are in $[a,b)$.  I hope you understand why if $x_{i} = b - \frac{1}{i}$, after a certain finite point, all successive terms *will* be in $[a,b)$.  And so, we could just as easily ignore all of those finitely many terms that are outside of $[a,b)$ and just consider the sequence gotten by starting at the first point of $x_{n}$ where all successive terms are in $[a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (b-(1/n))converges to b. So, one can find m in IN such that b-(1/n) is in (a,b+1) for n>=m. 
  => b-(1/n) is in (a,b) for n>=m.(for each such term is < b)

   Also, (b-(1/m),b-(1/(m+1)),...) converges to b. Take x_1 = b-(1/m), x_2 = b-(1/(m+1)),.... Maybe, your lecturer wanted you to work with some tail of (b-(1/i)).
```